# Delete multiple rows in SQLite 3

Tags: database, sqlite, rows

I have a SQLite 3 database with 9,000,000 rows. This database is provided by a third-party provider.

The first and second column (columnA and columnB) are not unique, but their combinations are unique. I have an index with these two columns, a and b.

My problem is that every day I have to delete a huge number of rows (5000...)

I tried a lot of methods like

```
PRAGMA secure_delete = 0;
begin;
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE columnA||columnB IN ('25914538421975',  '9127586254862',  '84525425668451','54529845321158',......);
commit;
.quit
```

It works, but it requires too long time to execute... (approximately
30 minutes).

During its working I can't access the database; it's locked.

Is there another command to delete multiple rows more quickly in SQLite 3?

Comment: The concatenation is not one of the fastest operations. Can you avoid it? Do you really want to check for concat? Assume A="23", B="45", concat A||B="2345". Do you want to delete rows which have A="2", B="345"? Try e.g. `where A='25914538' and B='421975'`. It might be faster, it might avoid deleting rows you actually want to keep. No problem if A and B are fixed length.

Comment: Hi Yunnosch
I am not usaual with sqlite command
I tried with this methode first 

DELETE FROM table_name WHERE columnA='259145684' and columnB ='21975';
and this command 5000 times, but it more than 30 minutes so I tried with concatenation

the column A has always a lengh of 9 and the B a lengh of 5

Comment: Don't use 5000 transactions but a single transaction.

Comment: Hi CL, thank for answer, but how to do what your say (a single transaction)? I think it is what I made with the code I put above...